# Dalsa Genie GigE vision camera for Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, networking, camera, peripherals

I am setting up a camera with my Raspberry Pi to test an optical layout on a high altitude balloon mission. I am using a Raspberry Pi model B. The camera will be required to take a still photo every 10 seconds.

I would like some expert input on whether or not my camera module will be able to interface with the Pi. It uses GigE vision, and has power pins so that I don't need the PoE adapter. Find attached the link to the module, and its data sheet.

Camera:
https://www.1stvision.com/cameras/models/Teledyne-Dalsa/Nano-M2590-NIR

Data sheet:
https://www.1stvision.com/cameras/dalsa/dataman/Teledyne-Dalsa-Genie-Nano-Series-User-Manual.pdf

Thanks,

Andrew R.

Comment: I think you're getting a lot of good answers on the forum...

Comment: you can find some information here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=216973